# Salesforce connectivity/timeout issues while connecting through mulesoft default connector

Tags: salesforce, mule, mulesoft, connector

I'm trying to connect to salesforce using Mulesoft OOB connector - using OAuth jwt, but I intermittently get timeouts (connect timeout and read timeout both are set to 10 secs). Is there a way I can find out how much time it is taking to connect to Salesforce ?

So that the root cause for these timeouts can be found out?

Comment: I think you need to work with the Salesforce team on how long it is taking to complete their job and give the response back. Another option is to increase the timeout and see if you still get the error.

Comment: What do you mean by "default" and "OOB" connector? There is no default connectors. You need to add them to your Mule applications explicitly. And there are several Salesforce related connectors, like the "Salesforce Connector", "Salesforce Commerce Cloud Connector", etc.

Comment: And you should share the configuration of the connector and the errors that you are seeing.